# How to arrange Columns in VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, sfdc-styleguide

I have a custom object page which is used to create record. Here I am struggling with styling, I used panel grid/html table/ pageblock section item but nothing is working. The styling is always getting disturbed when rendering.

I want to show the fields as showing in image (this is just an example)
[image]

Page :

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c" extensions="controllerClass" >
       <apex:form id="FormID" >
        <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>

        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!saveRec}"
                    value="Save" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>


            <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:outputPanel id="Name">
               <apex:actionRegion >
               <span class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap  first">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Account Name </span>
               <apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c.AccountId}">
                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!method1}"
                            rerender="panel1,panel2">

                            <apex:param assignTo="{!AccId}" value="{!customObject__C.AccountId}" />
                            </apex:actionSupport>

                   </apex:inputField></apex:actionRegion>
             </apex:outputPanel>

             <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <span class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap  first" style="font-size: 11px;">
              {!$ObjectType.customObject__C.fields.field__c.Label} </span>
             <apex:outputPanel id="panel2" >

              <apex:outputField value="{!customObject__C.panel2__c}" />
              </apex:outputPanel></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

              </apex:pageblocksection>

                <apex:pageblocksection >

                    <apex:inputfield value="{!customObject__C.Name}" />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!customObject__C.Abc__C}" />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!customObject__C.ttt__c}" />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!customObject__C.xyz__c}" />


            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!customObject__C.YYY__C}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!customObject__C.UUU__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!customObject__C.COMP__c}" />

                <apex:inputField value="{!customObject__C.Status__c}" />

                <apex:inputField value="{!customObject__C.Value__C}" />

            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: If you dont provide the CSS and how and where you are loading it, its kind of hard to see what you are doing wrong. maybe you can share it? Additionally, if you dont show us what behavior you are expecting css wise, its hard to propose a solution or point you in the right direction.

Comment: Share screenshot of your current UI. AFAICS first 2 `apex:pageBlockSection ` are causing ths issue.

Comment: @TusharSharma thanks for your reply I added my page image